# React wait for server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to write an application that requests some informations from an API. As long as this informations isn't available I don't want to continue with the rest of the application. I already tried this:

```
function suggestion(callback) {
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3001/');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var a = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(a);
        callback(a);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

var sugg = suggestion(function(lista) {
    var s = [];
    lista.forEach(element => {
        s.push(element.event);
    });  
    console.log(s);

    return s; 
});
```

Why sugg is returning undefined?

Comment: You are not returning anything from your `suggestion` function. Since it's asynchronous, you should pass all return values you are interested in as arguments to the `callback` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As long as this informations isn't available I don't want to continue with the rest of the application

That's not how you do this with web technologies (which are what you're using if you're using React, even if it's React native). Instead, you have the application show an appropriate "loading" or "pending" state while the asynchronous operation is outstanding, and then update that state when the operation completes.

> Why sugg is returning undefined?

`sugg` is `undefined` because `suggestion` doesn't have a return value. The result of calling a function that never does `return something` is always `undefined`. The fact your **callback** has a `return` doesn't matter, nothing is using what `callback()` returns in `suggestion` (and even if it did, it would be doing that *later*, not when `sugg` is being assigned to).

So taking those two bits of information together, we get:

```
function suggestion(callback){
    // (You probably need something declaring `xhr` and assigning
    // `new XMLHttpRequest()` to it here)
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3001/');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var a = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(a);
        callback(a);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

showPendingState();      // ***
suggestion(function(lista){
    var s = [];
    lista.forEach(element => {
        s.push(element.event);
    });  
    console.log(s);
    showRealStateUsing(s); // ***
});
```

**But**, I would suggest using a promise instead of a raw callback, and handling the error case. And if we're going to use a promise, let's use the modern `fetch` rather than the old XHR:

```
function suggestion() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        });
}

showPendingState();
suggestion()
    .then(showRealStateUsing) // `showRealStateUsing` receives the suggestion as an argument
    .catch(showErrorState);   // `showErrorState` receives the error as an argument
```

If you're targeting an environment that supports [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) (and/or transpiling), we can make that simpler:

```
async function suggestion() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/');
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
}

// (in an `async` function)
showPendingState();
try {
    showRealStateUsing(await suggestion());
} catch (error) {
    showErrorState(error);
}
```

Comment: I disagree on `async` / `await` being simpler but other than that; spot on.